# Fish shell list with +30 aliases

Tags: bash, shell, fish

I tried fish shell and like it so far - now I want to add all my aliases (+30, for servers and so on) and only found that I can add functions in my .config/fish/functions folder.

Is there an easier more "badge" way of importing them from a normal .bash_aliases file?

Comment: I do not know `fish`. Is it possible to write a file with 30+ aliases and `source` that file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fish has the same `alias` syntax as bash. It just converts the aliases to functions for you. All you need to do is `funcsave` them to make them "permanent".

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
awk -F '[ =]' '$1 == "alias" {print; print "funcsave", $2}' ~/.bashrc | source -
```

Comment: Thanks that did the job perfectly (except changing .bashrc with .bash_aliases)

Answer (score 7):

The first thing to note is that `alias` in fish does something very different from what it does in `bash`. In fish `alias` is just a way to write one-liner functions. In other words this

```
alias xyz 'echo hello'
```

is just a shortcut for writing

```
function xyz
    echo hello $argv
end
```

A lot of the time when people are talking about converting bash aliases to fish what they really want is the fish `abbr` command to create an abbreviation.

Glenn's answer may work for you but only if your bash aliases are so trivial they are compatible with fish syntax. Not something I would bet on without having reviewed your aliases.

You can start by just copying your aliases into either your *~/.config/fish/config.fish* or a file that you `source` from your config.fish. Then review them to see if they are valid fish statements.